# issue with ui-router not working in the angular app

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the URL router working for my app but for some reason it will not link the files.
I have created a simple plnkr to demonstrate the issue ...

can someone please assist

http://plnkr.co/edit/XQs2vP4vtqnBWGKqmJZz

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some misunderstandings:

1. You did not specify a `ui-view` to render to state into
2. You configured the states as named views, which makes only sense if you need more than one ui-view in parallel (nesting views is always possible)

## How to fix it

Use `<div ui-view></div>` in your views for normal views and use `<div ui-view="content"></div>` for named views (`content` is a custom name which you may choose at will).

Also, you can use the `ui-sref` attribute to link to specific states which is better practice than setting the `href` manually. In all demos below i showed both ways.

Note that normal views have a simpler state definition syntax:

```
.state('person', {
    url: '/persons',
    templateUrl: 'list1.html',
    controller: 'employeeCtrl'
})
```

## Demos

### [`Demo with normal views`](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJl7yfcZPbVkGEECpls3?p=preview) (for single views)

### [`Demo with named views`](http://plnkr.co/edit/LgJgZCdS33ArXadGfUt7?p=preview) (for multi-views)

In both cases you can nest views as a further exploration of the possibilites of ui-router (which makes it way superior to default angular routing):

### [`Demo with normal views and nesting`](http://plnkr.co/edit/tuMZHhLQW9TPSCtkQdam?p=preview)

### [`Demo with named views and nesting`](http://plnkr.co/edit/rtoD7Zu0x9Yhi4x8lHbF?p=preview)

Unlimited possibilities.