# Angular change url without executing routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-routing, route-provider

I'm trying to make facebook-like modal windows - for example you click on image and it opens in modal window and the url changes from `/` to `/img/dj27s_D` without rerendering the views and when you close the modal the url goes back to `/`.

I figured out that using

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

will just crash the application on the next `$digest`. I have also tried

```
$location.path = '';
```

but nothing happens. If I execute

```
$location.path('/img/id')
```

The $routeProvider will kick in and change the views. I dont want this to happen, just want to temporary change the url while the modal is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the router to use the previous route. For example this way in your controller:

```
lastRoute = $route.current;
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (e) {
  if (window.location.href.match(/\/view/) || window.location.href === '/') {
    $route.current = lastRoute;
  }
});
```

When `$route.current` does not change, full page refresh is not triggered. You might wish to do some regexp checks to keep your URL space tidy to prevent refresh, but it's a small price to pay.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the [Angular UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). You might be able to do what you're describing with a nested state / nested view, where the inner view pops up the modal. You can configure the URLs for each state as you want.

Edit: There may be a way without using UI-Router, but I haven't done that. Perhaps [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337093/updating-url-in-angular-js-without-re-rendering-view) is relevant to you.

A simple partial example of UI Router with a nested view, you'd put this in your controller:

```
$stateProvider.state('site', {
    url: "",
    templateUrl: 'app/parent.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ParentCtrl'
});

$stateProvider.state('site.child', {
    url: "/child",
    templateUrl: 'app/child.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ChildCtrl'
});
```

Then in the parent template, put this type of div:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

which will be where the child template will load within the parent template.  In the child template, you could try the modal dialog.

Comment: Is there any solution without the UI-router? If not please can you provide a simple example.

Comment: here are some examples that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22116618/675065

Comment: The thing is that my goal is to change the url, so when you press refresh or copy/paste the link in the address bar, you'll be redirected to the actual page, not the popup. I can't figure out how I can do this with UI-Router.

Comment: When the user has the popup open then hits refresh, do you want the user to route to the page with the popup, or without the popup?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I want the user to go to the page without the popup.